# android annotation for username and password using retrofit

Tags: android, rest, web-services, retrofit

http://192.168.0.101:8080/messenger/webapi/login/?name=zeeshan&password=123

Above is my url by which i get response "Login Successfull" and i am trying to get response on my android app but app is crashing

[Log, i have also tried @Query instead of @Path but its giving me same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtNHP.png)

I am using this annotation

`String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.101:8080/messenger/webapi/";`

```
 @GET("login/?name={name}&password={password}")
    Call<String> login(@Path("name") String name, @Path("password") String password);
```

---

LoginActivity

```
private void loginUser() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Log.e("TAG", name + " " + password);
    try {
        Call<String> call = api.login(name,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                String res = response.body();
                Log.e("TAG", res);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("TAG", t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("TAG",e.toString());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
@POST("/api/v1/users/login") //Your login url should look like this
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<JsonObject> login(@Field("name") String name,
                           @Field("password") String password);
```

Comment: I am not sending a Post Request. I just want to get String  response which is "Login Successfull"

Comment: Oh okay. Can you specify the line of your crash?
Here? String res = response.body();

Comment: no, its not going in onResponse function. its crashing here
Call<String> call = api.login(name,password);

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).